# Find all the combination of substrings that add up to the given string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I'm trying to create a data structure that holds all the possible substring combinations that add up to the original string. For example, if the string is `"java"` the valid results would be `"j", "ava"`, `"ja", "v", "a"`, an invalid result would be `"ja", "a"` or `"a", "jav"`

I had it very easy in finding all the possible substrings

```
    String string = "java";
    List<String> substrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int c = 0 ; c < string.length() ; c++ )
    {
        for( int i = 1 ; i <= string.length() - c ; i++ )
        {
            String sub = string.substring(c, c+i);
            substrings.add(sub);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(substrings);
```

and now I'm trying to construct a structure that holds only the valid substrings. But its not nearly as easy. I'm in the mist of a very ugly code, fiddling around with the indexes, and no where near of finishing, most likely on a wrong path completely. Any hints?

Comment: What's wrong with a `List<String>` to hold the valid substrings? Or are you really trying to find a datatype to _efficiently_ represent only the valid substrings?

Comment: Assuming you mean *proper* substrings, since the empty string is also a substring.

Comment: no no, its not about the structure, I'm constructing a `Set<List<String>>` but it could be even a two dimensional array, my problem is the logic, how to find the proper substrings

Comment: @aioobe yeps, proper not empty substrings

Comment: You should try recursion: Take the first character, split or no split after that, and partition the rest.

Comment: This code even does not compile. What is data type for c and i?

Comment: Not sure why nobody listed a trie for this. It is best suited for this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
static List<List<String>> substrings(String input) {

    // Base case: There's only one way to split up a single character
    // string, and that is ["x"] where x is the character.
    if (input.length() == 1)
        return Collections.singletonList(Collections.singletonList(input));

    // To hold the result
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // Recurse (since you tagged the question with recursion ;)
    for (List<String> subresult : substrings(input.substring(1))) {

        // Case: Don't split
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(subresult);
        l2.set(0, input.charAt(0) + l2.get(0));
        result.add(l2);

        // Case: Split
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(subresult);
        l.add(0, input.substring(0, 1));
        result.add(l);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[java]
[j, ava]
[ja, va]
[j, a, va]
[jav, a]
[j, av, a]
[ja, v, a]
[j, a, v, a]
```

Comment: I'm impressed, and as I need more characters to post a comment, I'll just repeat, I'm impressed

Comment: Thanks for posting. Great interview-question-practice. I find these type of questions really hard to get right quickly.

Comment: for me it definitely was hard, the additional trick is that it appears so easy, until you actually try it, thanks again.

Comment: you are super awesome!!! can i please please get the javascript version of this. My browser hangs when i try to do this in javascript.

Comment: @kashyaphp https://jsfiddle.net/u49qu6ut/ Note that for a string of length n there are 2^(n-1) results, so don't try it out with too big input.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is the problem of finding the [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of the length of the string, and using those compositions to make substrings. So there are 2^n-1 compositions of a number n, which could make it a bit time-consuming for long strings...

Answer (score 1):

Probably somebody would like another solution which is non-recursive and takes no memory to hold a list:

```
public static List<List<String>> substrings(final String input) {
    if(input.isEmpty())
        return Collections.emptyList();
    final int size = 1 << (input.length()-1); 
    return new AbstractList<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public List<String> get(int index) {
            List<String> entry = new ArrayList<>();
            int last = 0;
            while(true) {
                int next = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(index >> last)+last+1;
                if(next == last+33)
                    break;
                entry.add(input.substring(last, next));
                last = next;
            }
            entry.add(input.substring(last));
            return entry;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return size;
        } 
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(substrings("java"));
}
```

Output:

```
[[java], [j, ava], [ja, va], [j, a, va], [jav, a], [j, av, a], [ja, v, a], [j, a, v, a]]
```

It just calculates the next combination based on its index.

Comment: I liked this solution!!

Comment: It would make sense to use an array of lists rather than a list of lists. The array index would correspond to the way the string is divided into substrings. E.g., element 6 would correspond to binary 110 which puts no comma in the first space, a comma in the second place, and a comma in the third place: [ja,v,a].

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle, for array of lists it would be necessary to actually store all the combinations into the memory as you cannot have an array in Java which computes on the fly. I did the same, but for the list index.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone will look for the same algorithm in python, here is implementation in Python:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def compositions(s):
    n = len(s)
    for k in range(n):
        for c in combinations(range(1, n), k):
            yield tuple(s[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,) + c, c + (n,)))
```

Example how it works:

```py
>>> for x in compositions('abcd'):
...     print(x)
('abcd',)
('a', 'bcd')
('ab', 'cd')
('abc', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'cd')
('a', 'bc', 'd')
('ab', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

With a small modification you can generate compositions in different order:

```
def compositions(s):
    n = len(s)
    for k in range(n):
        for c in itertools.combinations(range(n - 1, 0, -1), k):
            yield tuple(s[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,) + c[::-1], c[::-1] + (n,)))
```

It will give you this:

```py
>>> for x in compositions('abcd'):
...     print(x)
('abcd',)
('abc', 'd')
('ab', 'cd')
('a', 'bcd')
('ab', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'bc', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'cd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

And with another small addition, you can generate only specified number of splits:

```py
def compositions(s, r=None):
    n = len(s)
    r = range(n) if r is None else [r - 1]
    for k in r:
        for c in itertools.combinations(range(n - 1, 0, -1), k):
            yield tuple(s[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,) + c[::-1], c[::-1] + (n,)))
```

```py
>>> for x in compositions('abcd', 3):
...     print(x)
('ab', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'bc', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'cd')
```

Answer (score 0):

A different recursive solution that just adds to the list results

```
static List<List<String>> substrings(String input) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (input.length() == 1) {
        result.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{input}));
    }
    else {
        //iterate j, ja, jav, jav
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i++ ) {
            String root = input.substring(0,i+1);
            String leaf = input.substring(i+1);
            for( List<String> strings: substrings(leaf) ) {
                ArrayList<String> current = new ArrayList<String>();
                current.add(root);
                current.addAll(strings);
                result.add(current);
            }
        }
        //adds the whole string as one of the leaves (ie. java, ava, va, a)
        result.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{input}));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solve by this code.

```
public static List<String> subsets(String s) {
if(Objects.isNull(s) || s.length() ==0){
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
int length = s.length();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { // Group loop
    String substring = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) { //
        if (i + j > length - 1) {
            substring = s.substring(j) + s.substring(0, ((i + j) - length) + 1);
        } else {
            substring = s.substring(j, j + i + 1);
        }
        result.add(substring);
    }
}
return result;}
```

**OUTPUT**

[a, b, c, d, ab, bc, cd, da, abc, bcd, cda, dab, abcd, bcda, cdab, dabc]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count with the below formula.

```
print(2**(len("ABCD")-1))
```

here I am using **ABCD** as my input string.