# Generate all combinations of string by space

Tags: java, recursion, combinations, permutation

Say i have a string `A B C D` - i want to end up with a `List<List<String>>` which will contain the following combinations:

```
[A,B,D,C]
[A,B C D]
[A B, C D]
[A B C, D]
[A, B C, D]
etc...
```

found a bunch of answered questions with similar requests where people asked for all combinations based on substring of a single string but was unable to tweak it to my needs.

Ay help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi.. it's not an assignment - I'm in the middle of a work day :) and struggling to get this done.. this is the closest i've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169587/find-all-the-combination-of-substrings-that-add-up-to-the-given-string

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it by recursion.
Have 2 strings, left and right. Shift the rightmost character to the right string, repeat until there's only 1 character in left string. Everytime you do so, apply the same function to the right string.

So if you have "ABCD", that gives you:

```
"ABCD"
"ABC" f("D")
"AB" f("CD")
"A" f("BCD")
```

Fully expended you get:

```
f("ABCD") {
    "ABCD"
    "ABC" f("D")
        f("D") {
            "D"
        }
    "AB" f("CD")
        f("CD") {
            "CD"
            "C" f("D")
                f("D") {
                    "D"
                }
        }
    "A" f("BCD")
        f("BCD") {
            "BCD"
            "BC" f("D")
                f("D") {
                    "D"
                }
            "B" f("CD")
                f("CD") {
                    "CD"
                    "C" f("D")
                        f("D") {
                            "D"
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

which gives you:

```
[["ABCD"], 
["ABC", "D"], 
["AB", "CD"], 
["AB", "C", "D"], 
["A", "BCD"], 
["A", "BC", "D"], 
["A", "B", "CD"], 
["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are `N-1` places to insert comma. So there are 2<sup>n-1</sup> variants of placements, and we can just walk all numbers in loop using range 0..2<sup>n-1</sup>-1 and get corresponding combinations.

For example, value 5=101<sub>binary</sub> corresponds to commas at the first and the last places (according to set bits), so combination is `[A, B C, D]`