# Splitting string into all possible substrings such that concatenating strings creates original string?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split a string in all possible ways such that when the substrings are concatenated, they equal the original string. For example, the output for "vba" would be [[vba], [v,b,a], [vb,a], [v,ba]]. This is the same question as [Find all the combination of substrings that add up to the given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169587/find-all-the-combination-of-substrings-that-add-up-to-the-given-string) but I am having trouble implementing in VBA. 
I am having a bit of trouble with my VBA code and I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas? This is my first time in VBA and I am more used to Java, so I think I may be reassigning my variables incorrectly?

I've tried to do it a few ways, but this is my most recent try:

```
Function solve(original) as Collection
    Dim result As New Collection
    Dim resultList As New Collection

    result.add Right(original, Len(original))
    resultList.add result

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j as New Collection

    For i = Len(original)-1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim nList as New Collection
        For Each j In resultList
            Dim split as Collection, add As Collection
            Set split = j
            split.add Mid(original, i, i+1), before:=1

            Dim first as String, second as String
            first=j(1)
            second = Mid(original, i, i+1) & first
            Set add = j
            add.Remove(1)
            If add.count = 0 Then
                add.add second
            Else
                add.add second, before:=1
            End If
            nList.add split
            nList.add add
        Next j
        Set resultList = nList
        Set nList = Nothing
    Next

    Set solve = resultList
End Function
```

Comment: I think a recursive method would work more in your favor. Should this work for all length strings? Let's say if i put in a string with a length of 1000?

Comment: I tried it recursively as well, but it was giving really weird output so turned it into this. Also, it can be assumed my input will never be greater than 20 letters.

Comment: So what would the expected outcome be for a word like “magic”?

Comment: Think of it as (length of string)-1 "bits" to flip between 1 or zero (each representing the presence/absense of a comma).  So count in binary from 0 to the total number of sets.

Comment: @skin it would be [[magic], [m,a,g,i,c], [ma,g,i,c], [m,ag,i,c], [m,a,gi,c], and so on]. This is essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169587/find-all-the-combination-of-substrings-that-add-up-to-the-given-string but in VBA