# Print all the substrings of a given string in order by size

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, substring, nested-loops

[This code I'm using is from this previously asked question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332162/print-all-the-combination-of-substrings-from-a-given-string-in-order-by-letter) 
This question has been asked and answered plenty of times but I'm specifically asking for the order to be listed by size from largest to smallest.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inputedWord = "ABIGWORD";

    for (String str : breakStringIntoPieces(inputedWord, 2))
    {
        System.out.print("\n") + str;
    }
}

                                                            //Pass in word and minimum
                                                            //substring length to print
public static List<String> breakStringIntoAllPossibleSubstrings(String str, int num)
{                                                               
    List<String> listOfSubstrings = new ArrayList<>();
    Boolean insideLoop = false;

    for(int i=0; i<=str.length()-num; i++)
    {
        for(int j=str.length(); j>=i+num; j--)
        {
            //System.out.println(str.substring(i, j));
            if (insideLoop) //This is simply to not add the complete string to the 
            {               //list. Only substrings

                listOfSubstrings.add(str.substring(i, j));
            }
            insideLoop = true;
        }
    }
    return listOfSubstrings;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
ABIGWOR
ABIGWO
ABIGW
ABIG
ABI
AB

BIGWORD
BIGWOR
BIGWO
BIGW
BIG
BI

IGWORD
IGWOR
IGWO
IGW
IG

GWORD
GWOR
GWO
GW

WORD
WOR
WO

ORD
OR

RD
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: (In no special order other than size. This is just a typed example.

```
ABIGWOR
BIGWORD
ABIGWO
BIGWOR
IGWORD
GWORD
ABIGW
IGWOR
BIGWO
IGWO
ABIG
BIGW
WORD
GWOR
GWO
ORD
ABI
BIG
IGW
WOR
AB
BI
IG
GW
WO
OR
RD
```

I could technically just loop through the returned list and find all the biggest substrings but that would add too many steps. I'm wondering if there's away to do it within the given method. I think the process involves manipulated the i and j iterators after each loop?

Comment: One way is to use the  `TreeSet` with custom comparator to order strings

Comment: @William let me know if the answer helps. Also, please use the primitive data type `boolean insideLoop` for efficiency.

Comment: @AdithyaUpadhya Thank you. This really helps. Could you explain what item1 and item 2 are? "for a String of size N, generating all substrings is of the order O(N^2)." That's technically too slow right? –

Comment: @WilliamToscano For any sorting operation, the elements in the list have to be compared by some logic. So, in the sort operation you specify the comparison logic for any two items in the list using a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-). Please refer tutorials on [comparator lambda expression](https://java2blog.com/java-8-lamba-expression-examples-using-comparator/). If this answer helps, don't forget to **upvote and mark it accepted**. It's one way to show gratitude to other folks.

Comment: @WilliamToscano "too slow" is relative. `O(N^2)` is polynomial time. Instead of substrings, for generating all **subsets** of a string, the operation is exponential `O(2^N)`. There's no better **serial processing** algorithm to generate substrings. You could improve execution speed by parallel processing though.

Comment: @AdithyaUpadhya Thank you so much for providing me resources to learn about Comparators! And for all the other answers! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this with minimal changes would be to sort the `listOfSubstrings` ArrayList by length and then return the result. This will just be a one line change using `Collections.sort`.

```
public static List<String> breakStringIntoAllPossibleSubstrings(String str, int num) {                                                               
    List<String> listOfSubstrings = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Your code added here... */

    // This will sort in descending order of length
    Collections.sort(listOfSubstrings, (item1, item2) -> item2.length() - item1.length());

    return listOfSubstrings;
}
```

In terms of time complexity, for a String of size `N`, generating all substrings is of the order `O(N^2)`.

An extra sorting operation will introduce `O(N^2 x log(N^2)) = O(N^2 x log(N))`.

Therefore, overall complexity will be `O(N^2 x log(N))`

Comment: Though not needed in this particular case, it's better to use `Integer.compare(item2.length(), item1.length())`, to make it a habit so you don't forget to do it when it matters.

Comment: In Java 8+, you can also use `listOfSubstrings.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed())`

Comment: Ah, the `comparingInt`. I keep forgetting about that. I'm still at awe at the simplicity of functional programming in Python. In Java, it's all jargon which I tend to forget now and then.

Comment: @AdithyaUpadhya So should I use Andreas code instead? Both of you posted some great code, but if it's better practice to use the comparingInt, let me know.

Comment: My personal preference would be `Integer.compare(item2.length(), item1.length())`. However, `(item1, item2) -> item2.length() - item1.length()` would be elaborate. If you've just started learning comparators and functional programming, the latter would be a good start. The former would be recommended for it's simplicity.